# Inquire about using a random integer as the size of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, random

so I have trouble remembering how to call upon random numbers in C++. I'm not sure how to, so if someone could remind me that would be fantastic. I'm trying to make a vector with a random size filled with random integers. Here is my following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    int main()
{
  int randSize = rand();
  int sum = 0;
  int product = 1;
  std::vector<int> numbers(randSize);
  int output;
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
  {
    int randNum = rand();
    numbers[i] = randNum;
    output = numbers[i]&2;
    if (output == 0)
    {
      sum += numbers[i];
    }
    else
    {
  product = product * numbers[i];
    }




  }

  std::cout << "The sum of even numbers is " << sum << "\n";
  std::cout << "The product of off numbers is " << product << "\n";



}
```

Comment: [What you know is best forgotten](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Rather than relearning it, [learn `<random>` instead](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), especially the example at the end, should get you going.

Comment: Warning about `std::vector<int> numbers(randSize);` though. The random numbers (even lowly old `rand`) can get pretty big and used as a `vector`'s size can easily run you out of available memory.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments, [best forget about `rand()`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and use the facilities provided by the standard library in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead. For example:

```
std::vector<int> makeRandomBunch(int min, int max, std::size_t min_elements, std::size_t max_elements)
{
    std::mt19937 generator(42);

    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> size_distribution(min_elements, max_elements);
    std::size_t num_elements = size_distribution(generator);

    std::vector<int> data;
    data.reserve(num_elements);

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> element_distribution(min, max);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data), num_elements, [&](){ return element_distribution(generator); });

    return data;
}
```

Here, we're using an [`mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) pseudorandom number generator (don't get spooked by the name, it's just named after [the algorithm it uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)) seeded with the value 42 as our source of randomness. An [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) can be used to shape the randomness provided by a random generator into random integers sampled from a given range. We use a `uniform_int_distribution` to randomly pick a size between `elements_min` and `elements_max` for our vector and [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) that amount of space in our vector. We use another `uniform_int_distribution` which we'll pick our `int` elements from (ranging between `min` and `max`). Finally, we use [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) in combination with a [`back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to fill our vector with elements and return the vector…

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Crandom%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%0Astd::vector%3Cint%3E+makeRandomBunch(int+min,+int+max,+std::size_t+min_elements,+std::size_t+max_elements)%0A%7B%0A++++std::mt19937+generator(42)%3B%0A%0A++++std::uniform_int_distribution%3Cstd::size_t%3E+size_distribution(min_elements,+max_elements)%3B%0A++++std::size_t+num_elements+%3D+size_distribution(generator)%3B%0A%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+data%3B%0A++++data.reserve(num_elements)%3B%0A%0A++++std::uniform_int_distribution%3Cint%3E+element_distribution(min,+max)%3B%0A++++std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data),+num_elements,+%5B%26%5D()%7B+return+element_distribution(generator)%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++return+data%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:44.627450980392155,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:26.04918890633177,l:'4',m:50.63091482649842,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:49.36908517350158,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:55.372549019607845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)